# Axios and fetch gives empty mapping in Golang even when url-encoded (header is added)

Tags: go, axios, fetch-api

I'm using axios to send http requests ( i used fetch also but it gives the same result ).

```
axios.post("http://localhost:3000/login",
            {
                answer: 42
            },
            {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                },
            })
```

In my go file I'm logging the response

```
func post(req *http.Request, res http.ResponseWriter) {
    req.ParseForm()

    fmt.Println(req.Form)
}
```

The log is as follows :

```
map[{"answer":42}:[]]
```

However i want it to be as follows :

```
map["answer":[42]]
```

(I get such when i use postman)

What is the issue with this.

Outgoing data for reference

[image: Outgoing data]

---

**UPDATE**

I used request ( built-in with nodejs) and also with jQuery ajax. Both of them work well.

Its just with **axios and fetch** which is not working

Here is the code :

- request

  The following code using nodejs request

  ```
  var request = require("request"); 
  var options = { method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/login',
    headers: 
     { 
       'cache-control': 'no-cache',
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    form: { answer: '42' } };

  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    console.log(body);
  });
  ```
- jQuery ajax

The following is my jQuery code

```
var settings = {
"async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://localhost:3000/login",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
  },
  "data": {
    "answer": "42"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

However, I am still unable to get axios and fetch to work. If someone finds it please update the answer

Comment: Are you calling `ParseForm` first?

Comment: yes I am calling req.ParseForm()

Comment: That's not shown in your quoted code. Please update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: You've added that one line, but most of the function is still `...`. Please update your question to include a MCVE.

Comment: Also, be sure to inspect the outgoing request in your browser's developer console to ensure that the request its sending is what you think it's sending.

Comment: I've added the image of outgoing request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
axios.post('http://localhost:3000/login', querystring.stringify({'answer': 42},headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
});
```

You can set query string parameters using the params config option,
It will definitely works:

```
axios.post("http://localhost:3000/login", "", {
    params: {answer: 42},
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
})
```

To find out more please read this https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/350#issuecomment-227270046

Comment: Please update the title of the question. It has nothing to do with GO :)